# finding the given element in the given array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of integers in which the difference of consecutive elements is only one

```
|arr[i]-arr[j]|=1, where |i-j|=1
```

without using linear search.

lets say suppose our array is

```
 arr[]=5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2,1;
```

We have to find out the index of the first occurrance of the given value say, `-1`
So,our output is `6`.

What could be our approach to solve this problem?

I have tried by taking the difference between the given number and the current element and move ahead with that.

But I think I am wrong because its also called linear search. Please help me out.

Comment: I think the better question is, can this be done in O(lgn) time, without sorting? Otherwise the gains can just be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cand <- 0
repeat:
    if arr[cand] == x:
       done
    else:
       cand <- cand + |arr[cand]-x|
```

The idea is - you can 'skip' every elements in between `cand` to `cand + |arr[cand]-x|` - the element cannot be there!

Comment: Would sorting the list and using binary search work in this case or is this more optimal?

Comment: No, sort will be `n lon(n)`, while worst case here will be `O(n)`

Comment: @npinti binary search works in `O(logn)`, this solution could decay to O(n) easily for `arr=[1,0,1,0,1,0,......1,2]` when searching for 2. So - if you can sort array as pre-processing, it would be better, othereise - no - as stated Alma Do.

Comment: @amit isn't the difference between two elements supposed to be 1 or -1  
1,-1,1.. difference is 2.

Comment: @Karthik yea, it was a mistake that I fixed (look at the editted comment) - still the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is OK because a linear search means you traverse every element once until you find the answer but you don't do that.